# How to prevent app from launching (go to initial view controller) before get response from url request in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        APICaller().fetchUser(completionHandler: {baseData, error in
            if let baseData = baseData{
                APICaller().fetchBaseData = baseData
            }
        })
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

I've code like that in AppDelegate.swift, what I expected is I want APICaller().fetchBaseData get response data from URL request before launching the Initial View Controller. But in this case the code don't wait until url request get response. That make the APICaller().fetchBaseData nil when access by initial view controller

Comment: You should load the data in your root view controller. Show some sort of "loading" indicator until the data is retrieved. Never do anything to delay the launch of the app.

Comment: if I load the data in my root view controller, so in what cycle I load it? is right if I load it in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: That's where I would call it from.

Comment: Either you put a intermediary ViewController that will show the initial one when the request has completed, or you add to your initial view controller a "waiting" mode until request is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a splash view controller until receive the response from the server when you get the response you can set a new root view controller:

(You can search in google about splash view design sample: a view with a logo of your app, the logo can have an animation for waiting such as heartbeat animation)

if you have scene delegate:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo
               session: UISceneSession,
               options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        sendYourRequestToServer()
        window?.rootViewController = yourSplashViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    func sendYourRequestToServer() {
        APICaller().fetchUser(completionHandler: {baseData, error in
            if let baseData = baseData{
                APICaller().fetchBaseData = baseData
                showRootView()
            }
        })
    }

    func showRootView() {
       window?.rootViewController = RootViewController //every view you want
       window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

if you have app delegate:

```
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launch options: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
       sendYourRequestToServer()
       window?.rootViewController = yourSplashViewController //a simple view that show on the launch before root view
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    func sendYourRequestToServer() {
        APICaller().fetchUser(completionHandler: {baseData, error in
            if let baseData = baseData{
                APICaller().fetchBaseData = baseData
                showRootView()
            }
        })
    }

    func showRootView() {
       window?.rootViewController = RootViewController //every view you want
       window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

I don't know what's your need in fail state maybe you can use such as a recursive function:

```
func sendYourRequestToServer() {
        APICaller().fetchUser(completionHandler: {baseData, error in
            if let baseData = baseData{
                APICaller().fetchBaseData = baseData
                showRootView()
            } else {
                sendYourRequestToServer()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: This is not a friendly user experience. Keep in mind cases where a user has a very poor network connection and the result never arrives. Making the user stare at a splash screen with no feedback is far from ideal.

Comment: @HangarRash it depends on the PO and UX Designer, This is just a solution, that's it. if the app should wait for the response, the user should wait until receives the response. it depends on the application.

Comment: @HangarRash and also he can add a toast or check network reachability, I wrote an answer for just the question.

Comment: maybe solution from Maziar can be accepted cause I just want to wait until url response get request before launching the app. But if the condition like @HangarRash said, maybe I just notify the user with new splash screen if the connection is not available at the moment